# filter buddypress users posts by user 'xprofile' custom fields

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, filters, buddypress

Hi I am struggling to figure out out how to make a filter for users posts by their profile fields.. example= Users registration form has select dropdown profile field of school years 2017, 2018 and then they create a post. filter all posts by that taxonomy of graduation year..so then you can only see posts by people of that school year. Is anyone aware of a plugin that could do this. the confusing part is posts are being loaded but filtered by member details. two separate directories.

Please help, or advice

Answer (score 0):

First you can save in a associative array the value of the school field and the user id who belongs this field value. You need to know the school field ID.

```
define(FIELD_ID, /* Insert field id here */);    
/* Save all site users */
$users = bp_core_get_users();
/* Create array for save fields values */
$user_xprofile_school = array();

/* Loop over each user and save the id and the school field value */
foreach ( $users as $user ):
        $index = 0;
        foreach ( $user as $u ):
            /* Check if value exists before save */
            if ( xprofile_get_field_data( FIELD_ID, $u->id, 'array' ) ):
                $users_xprofile_school[$index]['user_id'] = $u->id;
                $users_xprofile_school[$index]['field_school'] = xprofile_get_field_data(FIELD_ID, $u->id, 'array');
                $index++;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

This is going to return an array like this:

```
array([0] => ([user_id] => 1, [field_school] => 'years 2017'), [1] => ([user_id] => 2, [field_school] => 'years 2018'))
```

Then you can loop the users posts using the `field_school` index and the `user_id`.

This is not all the work but could be a good start point. Hope this help you.